Would it be appropriate to always use the latest available version of the Chromium driver, especially if
I am currently automating VS Code as a desktop application using Squish. Considering the frequent updates to the VS Code platform, Squish requires a matching Chromium driver version. Would it be appropriate to always use the latest available version of the Chromium driver, especially if a newer VS Code build is based on a Chromium version higher than V115?
For example, if VS Code is built on V122.0.6261.156 and I use Chromium driver package 126.0.6478.63, is this acceptable or should I specifically use the Chromium driver version V122.0.6261.156?
I tried to use latest chrome driver version(126.x.x) instead the exact version(122.x.x)
